# How to click on a <svg:image> element using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, svg, xpath, webdriverwait

Provided an xpath below:

```
<svg:image xlink:href="some.svg" class="holder-38" width="24" height="268" preserveAspectRatio="none" x="426.7" y="473" type="image/svg+xml" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-12238="12238">
```

I am able to access this with xpath (without tag as '*'):

```
'//*[@class="holder-38"]'
```

But unable to access with tag as `svg:image`:

```
'//svg:image[@class="holder-38"]'
```

How can I specify the tag here?

Comment: I have rolled back your last edit to the question, so the question title is more generic and helpful to the community and future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `<svg:image>`

The [`<svg:image>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/image) element includes images inside SVG documents. It can display [raster image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/raster_image) files or other SVG files. The only image formats SVG software must support are JPEG, PNG, and other SVG files. Animated GIF behavior is undefined.

SVG files displayed with `<image>` are [treated as an image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/SVG_as_an_Image) where external resources aren't loaded, [:visited](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited) styles [aren't applied](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Privacy_and_the_:visited_selector) and they cannot be interactive. To include dynamic SVG elements, try [`<use>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/use) with an external URL. To include SVG files and run scripts inside them, try [`<object>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/object) inside of [`<foreignObject>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject).

> **Note**: The HTML spec defines `<image>` as a synonym for [`<img>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img) while parsing HTML. This specific element and its behavior only apply inside SVG documents or [inline SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/SVG_In_HTML_Introduction).

---

### xlink:href

The [xlink:href](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/xlink:href) attribute defines a link to a resource as a reference [`<IRI>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Content_type#IRI). The exact meaning of that link depends on the context of each element using it.

> **Deprecated since SVG 2**: This feature is no longer recommended. Though some browsers might still support it, it may have already been removed from the relevant web standards, may be in the process of being dropped, or may only be kept for compatibility purposes. Avoid using it, and update existing code if possible; see the compatibility table at the bottom of this page to guide your decision. Be aware that this feature may cease to work at any time.
>
> **Note**: SVG 2 removed the need for the `xlink` namespace, so instead of `xlink:href` you should use [`href`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/href).

---

### Solution

To `click()` on the desired element you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired `element_to_be_clickable` and you can use the following solution:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[name()='svg:image' and starts-with(@class, 'holder') and contains(@xlink:href, 'some')]"))).click()
```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: but I don't wan't to use * as the tag - do you know how that could be avoided?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following way to access tag_name.

```
'//*[local-name()="svg:image"][@class="holder-38"]'
```

To click on the element use `Action` Class.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
elememnt=WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ec.presence_of_element_located(("xpath", '//*[local-name()="svg:image"][@class="holder-38"]')))
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(elememnt).click().perform()
```