# Get links from a svg interactive map

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, svg, web-scraping, webdriverwait

I am using webdriver.Chrome (Selenium), to get links that are stored under an svg interactive map, at the following URL: https://www.mpcb.gov.in/water-quality

I have tried to use different functions of find_elements_by_ like xpath, partial_text, and more but without success. This is the beginning of my code:

```
DRIVER_PATH = 'C:/Users/Asaf/Desktop/Asaf/Python/chromedriver.exe'
options = Options()
options.headless = True
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1200")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)
 
# Site URL
url='https://www.mpcb.gov.in/water-quality'
driver.get(url)
```

To put it in context, I want to get these links (the clickable arena of the map) in order to scrape data from them, one at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the links from a [svg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49024052/creating-xpath-for-svg-tag/49024531#49024531) interactive map, open the links in a new [tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28431765/open-web-in-new-tab-selenium-python/51893230#51893230) to scrape data from them, one at a time you can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Code Block:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.mpcb.gov.in/water-quality')
  hrefs = [my_elem.get_attribute("xlink:href") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[property='schema:text'] svg g a")))]
  parent_window  = driver.current_window_handle
  for href in hrefs:
      driver.execute_script("window.open('" + href +"')")
      WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(2))
      windows_after = driver.window_handles
      new_window = [x for x in windows_after if x != parent_window][0]
      driver.switch_to_window(new_window)
      print(driver.current_url)
      driver.close()
      driver.switch_to_window(parent_window)
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  https://www.mpcb.gov.in/water-quality/Thane/15
  https://www.mpcb.gov.in/water-quality/Nashik/18
  https://www.mpcb.gov.in/water-quality/Aurangabad/19
  https://www.mpcb.gov.in/water-quality/Amravati/21
  https://www.mpcb.gov.in/water-quality/Raigad/14
  https://www.mpcb.gov.in/water-quality/Pune/17
  https://www.mpcb.gov.in/water-quality/Nagpur/20
  https://www.mpcb.gov.in/water-quality/Chandrapur/23
  https://www.mpcb.gov.in/water-quality/Kolhapur/22
  https://www.mpcb.gov.in/water-quality/Mumbai/12
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Clicking on svg using selenium python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57075377/clicking-on-svg-using-selenium-python/57076157#57076157)
- [How to click on a svg:image element using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55491920/how-to-click-on-a-svgimage-element-using-selenium-and-python/55510681#55510681)
- [Creating XPATH for svg tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49024052/creating-xpath-for-svg-tag/49024531#49024531)

Comment: This answer works great! Thank you very much!